# SQL: SELECT all and Remove duplicated rows based on values from multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, duplicates, greatest-n-per-group

I have the following SQL table name 'orders':

```
+--------------+------------+-------------------+------------+
| order_id     | item_id    |   amount          | commission |
+--------------+------------+-------------------+------------+
|          111 | 1234       | 23                |          1 |
|          222 | 1234       | 34                |          2 |
|          111 | 2345       | 45                |          3 |
|          111 | 1234       | 23                |          1 |
+--------------+------------+-------------------+------------+
```

And I'm trying to Select only the rows that the order_id and item_id are NOT the same (remove duplicates only if BOTH has the same value), I tried using "Group_By" as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM orders GROUP BY order_id,item_id
```

but this, will remove all duplicates of order_id, and all duplicated of item_id, here is the result:

```
+--------------+------------+-------------------+------------+
| order_id     | item_id    |   amount          | commission |
+--------------+------------+-------------------+------------+
|          111 | 1234       | 23                |          1 |
|          222 | 1234       | 34                |          2 |
+--------------+------------+-------------------+------------+
```

I've tried using 'DISTINCT' too, but I need to select all columns in the result.

here is the expected result:

```
+--------------+------------+-------------------+------------+
| order_id     | item_id    |   amount          | commission |
+--------------+------------+-------------------+------------+
|          111 | 1234       | 23                |          1 |
|          222 | 1234       | 34                |          2 |
|          111 | 2345       | 45                |          3 |
+--------------+------------+-------------------+------------+
```

I hope its clear, Thank you.

Comment: Strange, that query raises an exception when I run it...

Comment: @eranLevi . . . What you are describing is handled by `SELECT DISTINCT`.  You should show that query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
select order_id, item_id, amount, commission
from (
    select t.*, row_number() over(partition by order_id, item_id order by commission) rn
    from mytable t
) t
where rn = 1
```

With your sample data, it is not easy to see exactly which `partition`  and `order by` clause you are looking for, so you might need to adjust them to your exact use case.

Comment: Actually, this is the only way that works when I used SUM to calculate the results, Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Simply:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM orders
```

Comment: @YogeshSharma, https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=593fcfc2469f7834ec561b0a2a0852a5

Comment: . . . After re-looking the sample data, `distinct` would be best. I would suggest to include columns too, if ops has more columns than specified then this would be invalid.

Comment: you are absolutely right.. I didn't knew I can use DISTINCT with * -> Thank you!

Comment: The answer is correct, but in my case it doesnt works with SUM (it added the other orders too), using "row_number" does the job, Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT DISTINCT` should do what you want

```
SELECT DISTINCT order_id, item_id, amount, commission
FROM orders;
```

If you have more columns, but only care about these being duplicated, then you can use `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
SELECT o.*
FROM (SELECT o.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY order_id, item_id, amount, commission ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) as seqnum
      FROM orders o
     ) o
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
create table MyTable
(order_id int
, item_id int
, amount int
, commission int)

insert into MyTable values
(111, 1234, 23, 1),
(222, 1234, 34, 2),
(111, 2345, 45, 3),
(111, 1234, 23, 1)

select distinct * from MyTable
```

Live [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=de071b987b7c4cc22d251c14378df2a5) demo.